# My elapsed time is only going up to 60

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datetime, timer

How can I create a elapsed time method that goes beyond 60 seconds AND counts only in seconds. My current implementation constantly repeats every 60 seconds.

CODE:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    time = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
    //DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}


public void timeSetup()
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    //timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

    timer.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: Its not really clear what you're asking, do you want a timer that counts only once after 60 seconds? Every second?

Comment: I want a timer that goes beyond 60 seconds, for example 61 sec, 62 sec, ..., 131 sec, etc

Comment: @Bart that implementation did not work, it gave the same output.

Comment: public static int time =0; then time++ in tick event (then google thread safety)

Comment: or (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds

Comment: Your timer is firing just fine. The reason you're not seeing 60, 61, 62... is because your Tick event handler is reading the second component of the current time of day (which can never go beyond 59, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make things harder than necessary:

```
class TimerClass
{
    public int time;

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time++;
    }


    public void timeSetup()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

        timer.Start(); 
    }
}
```

This calls the Tick handler every second and counts the number of times it is called. This can be imprecise for measuring long periods of time. For the long run, use

```
time = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds;
```

where startTime is initialized as the time when you start the timer.

Comment: This is not precise, as it does not count the seconds, but just the number of times the Tick handler is called. In the long run, there will be a deviation, as DispatcherTimer is not a real-time timer. Calculate the *actually* elapsad time as `(DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds` instead.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your suggestion; I edited it into my answer.